# Where does Windows 10 store info that appears in Windows Explorer when I open "This PC"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, drobo

I have a network storage device (a Drobo device that's at least 5 years old) that I connect to from time to time. When I do, it appears as A:. Recently I've been having problems connecting to it. The app that comes with the device does not see it when I connect to it.

The device is now entirely disconnected. But when I am looking in "This PC" in Windows Explorer I am seeing A: as if this were that network device. It's showing a small fraction of the files that are supposed to stored there and when I try to open any of them it says the files do not exist. So it appears to be some sort of "ghost" from one my earlier connections.

I am wondering if clearing this ghost would somehow help with the connectivity issue. Where is this info saved in Windows 10? In the registry somewhere? If so, what should I be looking for when I open `regedit`?

Comment: Try that device on another computer and see how it behaves there. If all goes well, then that could help. If same, then its just the device.

Comment: "I have a network storage device (a Drobo device that's at least 5 years old)"   <-- Make sure it is not tied to SMBv1 (completely removed from Windows 10 later versions).

Answer (score 1):

Icons listed under "Network locations" can be one of:

- A **mapped drive**, i.e. a share with a drive letter assigned. You should be able to right-click it and use "Disconnect network drive", or use `net use X: /d` to unmap it.

  Mapped drives can be either temporary, or persistent (re-established upon login). If everything else fails, remove the registry subkey underneath `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network` that corresponds to the mapped letter:

  ```
  reg delete HKCU\Network\X /f
  ```
- Just a **shortcut** to the share, which is stored in the filesystem (as a `*.lnk` file) at:

  ```
  ~\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts\
  ```

  You should be able to delete it, either from that folder or directly from "This PC".

  (This is the same thing that used to be shown under "My Network Places" and stored at `~\NetHood` in previous Windows versions, i.e. 2000/XP.)

In both cases the share is still accessed the same way (i.e. through SMB), and I suspect that "Offline Files" is involved – it's a standard Windows feature which locally caches parts of network shares, so that you could continue working with the share offline.

Sometimes the "Offline Files" cache gets confused. You cannot access the cached files directly (though they're stored somewhere in C:\Windows\CSC) but you can tell the service to reset everything on reboot:

- [KB 942974: You can still access offline files even though the file server is removed from the network on a Windows 7-based client computer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/access-offline-files-file-server-removed-from-network)
- [KB 230738: How to reinitialize the offline files cache and database in Windows XP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/re-initialize-offline-files-cache-database)